# Appium takes more than 5 min to get response while automating iOS app

Tags: ios, appium, webdriver-io

I Have observed that when I first time run my script that will run very fast without any delay response. However, immediately, if I run the same script without any changes or closing simulator or any kind of reset, following POST request takes more than 5 min to get a response.

**Request from Appium:**

`[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"XXX.XXXX.ios","arguments":[],"environment":{},"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}`

**Response:**

`[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"91784C9C-3B63-40D3-9335-9C80548E7E68","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":null,"sdkVersion":"11.4","CFBundleIdentifier":null}},"sessionId":"91784C9C-3B63-40D3-9335-9C80548E7E68","status":0}`

**Following are my configured version**

- Xcode Version: Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
- Appium: v1.8.1 also
  tried with v1.9.1
- node: 5.6.0
- Javac: javac 1.8.0_171
- Device: Simulator (iPhone 7)
- Appium Java-client: 6.1.0

**Full Appium log:**

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app","noReset":false,"unhandledPromptBehavior":true,"deviceName":"iPhone 7","version":"","platform":"MAC","newCommandTimeout":1500,"platformVersion":"11.4","automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"iPhone","platformName":"IOS","udid":"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924","autoAcceptAlerts":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":true},"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app","appium:autoAcceptAlerts":true,"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"iPhone","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 7","appium:newCommandTimeout":1500,"appium:noReset":false,"platform":"MAC","platformName":"ios","appium:platformVersion":"11.4","appium:udid":"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924","unexpectedAlertBehaviour":true,"unhandledPromptBehavior":true,"version":""},"firstMatch":[{}]}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app","noReset":false,"unhandledPromptBehavior":true,"deviceName":"iPhone 7","version":"","platform":"MAC","newCommandTimeout":1500,"platformVersion":"11.4","automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"iPhone","platformName":"IOS","udid":"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924","autoAcceptAlerts":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app","appium:autoAcceptAlerts":true,"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","browserName":"iPhone","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 7","appium:newCommandTimeout":1500,"appium:noReset":false,"platform":"MAC","platformName":"ios","appium:platformVersion":"11.4","appium:udid":"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924","unexpectedAlertBehaviour":true,"unhandledPromptBehavior":true,"version":""},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1539403642546 (09:37:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[BaseDriver] The capabilities ["platform","unexpectedAlertBehaviour","version"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.84.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   browserName: iPhone
[Appium]   platform: MAC
[Appium]   platformName: ios
[Appium]   unexpectedAlertBehaviour: true
[Appium]   unhandledPromptBehavior: true
[Appium]   version: 
[Appium]   app: /Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app
[Appium]   autoAcceptAlerts: true
[Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
[Appium]   deviceName: iPhone 7
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 1500
[Appium]   noReset: false
[Appium]   platformVersion: 11.4
[Appium]   udid: 7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"browserNam... and MJSONWP desired capabilities [object Object] were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"browserNam...
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: unhandledPromptBehavior, platform, unexpectedAlertBehaviour, version.
[XCUITest] The capabilities 'autoAcceptAlerts' and 'autoDismissAlerts' do not work for XCUITest-based tests. Please adjust your alert handling accordingly.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 7b782b91-6f85-433d-b713-070a891c95f9
[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'user.name'
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '9.4.1' (tools v9.4.0.0.1.1526532315)
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '11.4'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1539403642636 (09:37:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 9.4.1 with udid '7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924'
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924', real device: false
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1539403642857 (09:37:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Checking whether app '/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app' is actually present on file system
[debug] [XCUITest] App is present
[debug] [iOS] Getting bundle ID from app '/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app': 'XXX.XXXX.ios'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1539403642858 (09:37:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Not scrubbing third party app in anticipation of uninstall
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1539403643079 (09:37:23 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting log capture for iOS Simulator with udid '7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924', using 'xcrun simctl spawn 7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924 log stream --style compact'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1539403643385 (09:37:23 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Setting up simulator
[debug] [iOS] No reason to set locale
[debug] [iOS] No iOS / app preferences to set
[debug] [iOSSim] Matched 1 Simulator cache item for cleanup: /Users/user.name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging
[debug] [iOSSim] Setting preferences of 7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924 Simulator to {"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] Setting common Simulator preferences to {"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] Updated 7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924 Simulator preferences at '/Users/user.name/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' with {"DevicePreferences":{"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924":{"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}},"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] The count of running Simulator UI client instances is 1
[iOSSim] Both Simulator with UDID 7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924 and the UI client are currently running
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'simStarted' logged at 1539403643658 (09:37:23 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Verifying application platform
[debug] [XCUITest] CFBundleSupportedPlatforms: ["iPhoneSimulator"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Reset requested. Removing app with id 'XXX.XXXX.ios' from the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Installing '/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app' on Simulator with UUID '7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924'...
[debug] [XCUITest] The app has been installed successfully.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1539403647212 (09:37:27 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[debug] [XCUITest] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"state\" : \"success\",\n    \"os\" : {\n      \"name\" : \"iOS\",\n      \"version\" : \"11.4\",\n      \"sdkVersion\" : \"11.3\"\n    },\n    \"ios\" : {\n      \"simulatorVersion\" : \"11.4\",\n      \"ip\" : \"192.168.2.4\"\n    },\n    \"build\" : {\n      \"upgradedAt\" : \"1539327134564\",\n      \"time\" : \"Oct 12 2018 12:22:23\",\n      \"productBundleIdentifier\" : \"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"163984B3-334E-4054-AB68-99D93F26F976\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
[XCUITest] Will reuse previously cached WDA instance at 'http://localhost:8100/'. Set the wdaLocalPort capability to a value different from 8100 if this is an undesired behavior.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1539403647303 (09:37:27 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Using provided WebdriverAgent at 'http://localhost:8100/'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1539403647304 (09:37:27 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"state\" : \"success\",\n    \"os\" : {\n      \"name\" : \"iOS\",\n      \"version\" : \"11.4\",\n      \"sdkVersion\" : \"11.3\"\n    },\n    \"ios\" : {\n      \"simulatorVersion\" : \"11.4\",\n      \"ip\" : \"192.168.2.4\"\n    },\n    \"build\" : {\n      \"upgradedAt\" : \"1539327134564\",\n      \"time\" : \"Oct 12 2018 12:22:23\",\n      \"productBundleIdentifier\" : \"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"163984B3-334E-4054-AB68-99D93F26F976\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"


**[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"XXX.XXXX.ios","arguments":[],"environment":{},"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}**


[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"91784C9C-3B63-40D3-9335-9C80548E7E68","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":null,"sdkVersion":"11.4","CFBundleIdentifier":null}},"sessionId":"91784C9C-3B63-40D3-9335-9C80548E7E68","status":0}
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1539403968659 (09:42:48 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1539403968659 (09:42:48 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if this is an undesired behavior.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'orientationSet' logged at 1539403968660 (09:42:48 GMT+0530 (IST))
[Appium] New XCUITestDriver session created successfully, session 7b782b91-6f85-433d-b713-070a891c95f9 added to master session list
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1539403968660 (09:42:48 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"capabilities":{"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"iPhone","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"platformName":"ios","unhandledPromptBehavior":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":true,"version":"","app":"/Users/user.name/Desktop/XXXXX.app","autoAcceptAlerts":true,"automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"iPhone 7","newCommandTimeout":1500,"noReset":false,"platformVersion":"11.4","udid":"7B7A3A94-372F-4872-8BD0-F7BC50CA2924"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your tests with capability `noReset: true` and don't close/start driver before each test: you can use `driver.launchApp()` simply to restart it.